# How to get the value of a textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, findviewbyid

I tried:

```
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.date);
    String s1 = textView1.getText().toString();
```

but on the second line falls error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ancort.cryptophone.guitest.CAMyTest.testMail_000(CAMyTest.java:94)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:177)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1619)
```

Also, I tried

```
    TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewByID(R.id.date);
    String s = textView1.getText().toString();
```

But in this case "findViewByID" red highlights with error"cannot resolve method findViewById(int)". I understandthat the class must be extends from Activity class, but my class extends from another class. How to get the value of a textview?

Comment: Are you putting this code before setContentView?

Comment: show your xml code of layout

Comment: please post your complete code.

Comment: it's a context problem, till us what's the case here so that we can properly help you, is it a fragment? a regular class out of the Activity to achieve some needs? please illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

you are inside a Fragment if you are using getActivity, and probably, the view, is only part of the fragment itself.

change

```
 TextView textView1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.date);
```

with

```
 TextView textView1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.date);
```

if you are using that line after `onCreateView`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Fragment. Inside onCreateView write

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout,container, false);                                                                         
TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
```

Hope this will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted get a value that was in TextView. The decision was simple:

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) solo.getView(R.id.date); String s1 =
textView1.getText().toString();
```

Thank you all.